# Do we have mouse over event in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

Do we have mouse over event in android? I want to set text on a particular `TextView` on which my mouse is and dropped. Example: I want to drag a textview1 and drop it on another textview2 so I can set text of textview1 to textview2.

I had done the drag & drop examples but I can not found on which control my mouse is.

Comment: Mouse??? in android??? Where did you get the cursor??

Comment: where is the mouse in the phone.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar - we don't have mice in the phone. Only bugs.

Comment: i mean how can i get ACTION_OVER event in the android...
i want to on which control i m moving or droping...
mean i want to on which control(view) ACTION_UP event call...???????
@ShashankKadne.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a mouse on `Android`, like that tablet that has a docking `station`+`keyboard`.

You need a `OnGenericMotionListener` ..

```
OnGenericMotion(...., MotionEvent me) {
   if (me.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE) {

   }
```

`api14+` needed

[confirmed] Found me a tablet with usb mouse and can confirm this works for mouse movement. You WILL get flooded with messages, so simple operations or sleeping should be considered.